# Web-module isolation in jboss 4.2.2 when deployed inside a isolated .EAR file

Tags: jboss, deployment, classloader, isolation

How can one reach web-module isolation (i.e. each contained web-app is isolated from the others in the same .EAR) in jboss 4.2.2 when deployed inside a isolated .EAR file?

Jboss 4.2.2 keeps warning that web-module (jboss-web) level deployment descriptor class loading configuration is ignored when deployng an EAR file.

Answer (score 1):

In 4.0.x it does in this way:

- deploy/ear-deployer.xml

Change attribute 'Isolated' from    'false' to 'true' Ex: true

```
   Change attribute 'CallByValue' from    'false' to 'true' Ex: <attribute    name="CallByValue">true</attribute>
```

- conf/jboss-service.xml

Change attribute 'CallByValue' from 'false' to 'true' Ex: true

- deploy/jbossweb-tomcat55.sar/META-INF/jboss-service.xml

Change attribute 'Java2ClassLoadingCompliance' from 'false' to 'true' Ex: true

Change attribute 'UseJBossWebLoader' from 'false' to 'true' Ex: true

Thanks,
Mohit

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mohit but this solution wouldn't be viable since in the same jboss server instance other 3rd parties applications could be running and I wouldn't like to affect them.